# Is there a way to keep a on going log of all commands made in Cygwin?

Tags: cygwin

I am running cygwin on windows 8 and was wondering if there is a way to keep a log of all commands made in cygwin terminal?

Comment: More than the [history](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-History-Builtins.html) command already provides?

Comment: ....feeling stupid. Probably is stupid.  But yeah, is there a way to have cygwin have a ongoing command list in a text file of some sort?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think Cygwin alone has a logging functionality similar to something like PuTTy. However, you can use history which is logged by Bash (which you are using if you have a default Cygwin setup).

If you are using Bash, then your history is stored in `.bash_history`. You can use the [`history`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-History-Builtins.html) command to access the file easily.

You can pipe `history` and `grep` together to search your history:

```
history | grep "cd"
```

If you need more history to be stored, you can change your `HISTFILESIZE` in your `.bashrc`:

```
export HISTFILESIZE=100000
```

Comment: You can run `history | grep "what you want to search"` from any directory. You can run `echo "export HISTFILESIZE=100000" >> ~/.bashrc` (this adds `export HISTFILESIZE=100000` to the end of your `.bashrc` file) from any directory.

Comment: Thanks! I've added it to .bashrc